# Angular - Display another route than the url one

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Here is the scenario :

- I'm on `/group/`
- I click on a group, thus trying to go to `/group/:id`
- My AuthGuard is called with the activated route, resolves and check for `CanActivate`
- `CanActivate` detects the user should not go to the route.
  The user may have lost his rights between the time the group list was retrieved, and he tried to access a particular one.

Current behavior is that if I return false, the url will never be activated. If I return true, the url will be activated, but then, the whole component tree will be rendered, and all the `router-outlet` need to be physically present.

**What I would like to do :**

The url should be activated (i.e. `/group/:id` is in the url and history) but the page displayed should correspond to another route (e.g. `/404` or `/login`).
I insist on the fact that the url in the adress bar must remain the original `/group/:id`.

**I have thought about two possibilities :**

- Having a local 404 component, and hiding the router-outlet, displaying the 404 if needed.
  But the problem is the 404 component should be global, nested templates from root to the url should not be displayed. It not just the last part that is invalid, but the whole route.
- So instead, I could have a service storing informations about if we should show a 404, and then, a top-level component hiding the router-outlet and displaying the 404 when needed.

Though, these solutions don't seem perfect to me. They just get around the problem, without actualy solving it.
In particular, the `router-outlet` can't be `*ngIf`ed, meaning that even though I am displaying a 404, or a login page, the DOM will be populated with the whole website components of the activated route, but without any data, and even though the user should not see it. It seems ugly to me.
I'm not trying to get around the fact that router-outlet should be present to resolve the route, I just want angular to pretend a route on the url, and activate another one.

What is the proper way of implementing this behavior using Angular ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest answer, I dug into the `Router` class and figured we can pass `{skipLocationChange: true}` to `Router.navigate` in order not to update the url.

So, when the route is activated, in the constructor of the component, I just need to check if the route parameters resolved to a valid object, and if it is not the case, I silently navigate to the 404 :

```js
@Injectable()
export class GroupResolve implements Resolve<Group> {
    constructor() {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        return api.getGroup(route.params['id']);
        /* Returns null if user can't access such a group */
    }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'group.component.html',
    providers: [ GroupResolve ]
})
export class GroupComponent {
    constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
        if(route.snapshot.data['group'] == null) {
            /* The user can't access the given group page, silently navigate to a global 404 route */
            this.router.navigate(["404"], {skipLocationChange: true});
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the Angular 2 way to do that:

a) for pages not found there is fallback path "**"

```
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
}
```

b) for protected pages there is the onActivate mechanism

```
{
    path: 'private',
    component: PrivateComponent,
    canActivate: [Guard]
}
```

I don't think you have to hide or ngIf-fy the router-outlet. The router outlet is present all time and is crucial part of the application.

Plunkr:

- Go in windowed mode to be able to check the route in the address bar
- Click at "Navigate to non existing page": the address bar shows "/non-existing" but in fact you see 404 component
- Click at "Navigate to private": the Guard returns false which means that the navigation gets cancelled. Since there is a subscription to events Observable on router the user will be redirected to the login page. "/login" is what you see in the address bar.

https://plnkr.co/edit/FSklRhhQV0cpLFP53I13

Comment: Well, this does not really answer my question...
a) For the fallback route, I'm already using it, but I would like to display the fallback route content for a valid route, where the param is invalid, i.e. rejected by my auth guard.
b) This solution is maybe the prettiest one, but as the downside of actualy changing the url. This is exactly what I wanted to avoid.